# self.perform segue causes view to not conform

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have programmatically created a view layout with a content view, when this controller is the initial view controller I get something like this.

:[image]

When I have another view controller and segue to this viewcontroller, I get something like this:

[image]

Attached is my View Class:

```
class TestView: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
    setupConstraints()
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
func setupViews() {
    self.addSubview(contentView)
}
func setupConstraints() {
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    // check what safearealayoutguide is
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        print("IOS11 Screen")
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    } else {
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    } else {
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
}
let contentView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width))
    //view.layer.backgroundColor = CGColortran
    view.layer.borderWidth = 1
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    return view
}()
}
```

then my view controller:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func loadView() {
    self.view = TestView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
}
}
```

When this is the only screen in the application, it works. when I add another view controller and do a `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoginUser", sender: nil)`  it seems to break the view. What's going on here?

Comment: comment `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: Seemed to work! Read in to it, Not sure why having a segue changes that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

as currently you mix setting a frame `TestView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)`  with constraints , the above line is used only for a view when you set constraints to it as it invalidates the frame